# Python: attribute sharing between class and nested class

Tags: python, class, reference, nested

There's something about indirectly linking to an attribute that apparently I don't understand. If I have a class, and I create a nested class which has a variable that points to the parent/controller class variable, I thought it should change when the controllers variable changes.

Example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A_value = 10
        print("A_value in A after init:     " + str(self.A_value))
        self.B = self.B(self)
        print("")
        print("A_value in A after B init:   " + str(self.A_value))
        print("B_value in B after B init:   " + str(self.B.B_value))

    class B():
        def __init__(self, controller):
            self.B_value = controller.A_value
            print("B_value in B after init:     " + str(self.B_value))
            controller.A_value = 1
            print("B_value in B after change:   " + str(self.B_value))

A()
```

which results in

```
A_value in A after init:     10
B_value in B after init:     10
B_value in B after change:   10

A_value in A after B init:   1
B_value in B after B init:   10
```

What I expect to happen is `B_value` to be 1 at the end too, since it points to `A_value`. Why doesn't `B_value` change? Honestly, I don't understand why half my code works if this doesn't. And I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to search for the correct, I know that this is definitely answered in some way somewhere.
(tested in Python 2.7 and 3.7)

Comment: There is no subclasses in the code you posted. subclass != nested class

Comment: ok, I changed the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't changing the existing *value* that the `A_value` attribute references; you are changing what the name itself refers to. That has no effect on the original object still referenced by the `B_value` attribute. You'll want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a good overview of how exactly Python names work.

`self.A_value = 10` makes `self.A_value` reference a particular object in memory; call it `M1`, which is an `int` object representing 10.

`self.B_value = controller.A_value` results in `self.B_value` referencing the same object `M1`.

`controller.A_value = 1` does not affect `M1` at all; it makes `controller.A_value` refer to a new object (call it `M2`) that represents 1. The `B_value` object still refers to `M1`.

Comment: thanks for the Link, this is very helpful indeed. I'm amazed how I came this far without running into this issue.

Comment: maybe as a bit of addendum: so if I assign a mutable, for example 'self.A_value = [1]', and then referenced it with 'self.B_value = controller.A_value' and changed it via 'self.B_value[0] = 10', it would actually change the value (which explains why most of my code works anyways, because I'm using lists and dictionaries all over the place)

Comment: That change isn't really an assignment. It *looks* like an assignment, but it's really a mutating method call, equivalent to `setattr(self.B_value, 0, 10)`. You aren't changing the references, only the object both refer to.